# Adding JDK path from WSL2 Ubuntu to IntelliJ IDE frozen the screen

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, windows-10, wsl-2

As you guys can see from the images. I am trying to connect by WSL2-Ubuntu with IntelliJ by following this documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html#local_project. When I give JDK path and click on Apply or Ok it froze the screen. This happens every time I try and only leaves with me the option to close the IDE using task manager. JDK path that I am using is: \wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\lib\jvm\java-11-openjdk-amd64. Any idea why it must be behaving in such a way?

[image]

Comment: HI, I am from JB support. Log and ThreadDumps are needed to see what is going on while the IDE is frozen. Please restart the IntelliJ IDEA, reproduce the freeze and share the [logs folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) via https://uploads.jetbrains.com. Tell the upload ID after that

Comment: Hi @KonstantinAnnikov, I have uploaded the whole log folder. 

Upload id: 2021_07_22_Hh7GVgZBgJ7cyFu5 (file: log.7z)

Comment: Could you please try 2020.2 Preview version https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ There were many improvements in this area that may already fix this problem. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270081

Comment: Thank @KonstantinAnnikov, version 2020.2 solved the JDK frozen issue.  :)

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov I'm using IntelliJ 2023.2, and I still got a frozen issue. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the 2021.2 version of IntelliJ IDEA. Until it is released, you can download it at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is still an issue at least with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Build #IC-223.8836.41). Every time I add a WSL JDK, it freezes.

Comment: ... And the same happens with 2023.1 RC

Comment: Same here on 2023.1..

Comment: Turn off Windows defender before you do so

Answer (score 2):

You should shutdown any WSL instance before trying to add JDK WSL path via Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1, so the issue persists in newer versions.
The issue is related to real time virus monitoring. You should create security exceptions for IntelliJ folders and processes as described in the following links. Good luck.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006298560

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005028939-Slow-startup-on-Windows-splash-screen-appears-in-more-than-20-seconds